# Is vendoring a standard approach or is it obsolete?

Tags: go, vendoring

I'm about to setup a new project in Go.  I came across the term vendoring.  Is this standard or an obsolete concept.  I'm coming from a nodejs world and this feels like copying the nod_modules folder to a separate directory or am I confusing the whole purpose of this?

Comment: Vendoring is not obsolete. It is a useful technique for a certain cases. But note that vendoring _never_ was ought to be _the_ solution to dependency management. It had, has and will have its niche.

Comment: thanks, for this, can you give me a such a niche scenario, just want to be aware when I should be using this approach.

Comment: If you cannot use Go modules, e.g. because you have not network connectivity during   build. If your background is NodeJS: Do not use vendoring.

Answer (score 5):

It's not technically obsolete, but most cases should use [go modules](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules) instead.